# Ruby TCP: Any benchmarks?

Tags: ruby, networking, tcp

I have a remote server that needs to be able to accept multiple simultaneous connections from clients on a specific port. I need the connections to be fast and reliable.

I am planning to use TCPServer on the remote side and TCPSocket on the client side. There'd likely be 200+ connections to the server.

Do we have any known benchmarks in Ruby for a system like this? 
Also, do I need to worry about the underlying data multiplexing at socket level or Ruby/OS libraries take care of the same?

Finally, will you folks be able to recommend me any specific links/books that talk about designing systems like this? I googled but books about networking in Ruby seem to be an oddity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off leveraging [EventMachine](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html). It should be pretty fast and efficient.

EDIT: have a look at:

[this](http://20bits.com/articles/an-eventmachine-tutorial/) and [this](http://www.igvita.com/2008/05/27/ruby-eventmachine-the-speed-demon/)

Comment: Why? Application Programming efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

A multi-client TCP server generally creates a separate thread for each client.  Therefore, it can handle as many connections as the machine/OS will allow. This limitation is managed by the kernel.  So, as far as benchmarks go, it really depends on the performance of your machine.

Here is a link to some examples/tutorials for Ruby Socket Programming:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm